# Firebase Database Child Count

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android App which receives data from Firebase Realtime Database. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9gYW.png) is a Snapshot of my Database.

I want to get the number of children under the `Comments` field.

Here is my code:

```
public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;

    ImageButton commentPostButton;
    TextView DisplayNoOfInterest;
    int countComments;
    String currentUserId;
    DatabaseReference CommentsRef;

    public PostsViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        commentPostButton = (ImageButton) 
        mView.findViewById(R.id.commentPost);
        DisplayNoOfInterest = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.interest);

        CommentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    }

    public void setCommentStatus() {
        CommentsRef.child("Posts").child("Comments").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener())
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                 if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                     countComments = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                     int cc = Integer.toString(countComments)
                     DisplayNoOfInterest.setText(cc);
                 }
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reference is wrong. You need to pass the `postID` before trying to get comments, because the comments node is under each `postID`.

After referencing the right node, then you can call : `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`

Example:

```
CommentsRef.child("Posts").child(POSTID).child("Comments").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()){ 
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

            countComments = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }
        DisplayNoOfInterest.setText(Integer.toString(countComments));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(yourPostId).child("Comments").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    DisplayNoOfInterest.setText(""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I hope that can help you!

Thank You.